# Using JavaScript so that background image always stays the same when scrolling (plus other inquiries)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a webpage. Code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/saTfR/50/

I would like to insert a menu on the left side which will scroll down to different sections of the webpage which I will later add. I want the background map image to always stay in the same position when scrolling. I would like to make a section in the menu called "Portfolio" which will scroll down to different PNG images which I will insert. I would like for the user to be able to click on a PNG image and a new tab will open so that the user can better see the image.

I would also like my logo.png image to be displayed on the top-right hand corner of the page and be visible whenever the user scrolls up and down. (The logo cannot be currently displayed in the link because it is saved in my computer).

HTML:

```
 <p class="text">text</p>        
<img id="map" src="http://www.local-guru.net/img/guru/worldglow.png" alt="map"/>
<p class="text">text</p>      


<div class="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="logo2.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {font-family: Lucida Console; }

.text{
    color:white;
    z-index:999;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    left:60%;
    font-size:25px;}
</style>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".text").hide().fadeIn(2000);
var mywindow = $(window);
var pos = mywindow.scrollTop();
mywindow.scroll(function() {
    if(mywindow.scrollTop() > pos)
    {
        $('.text').fadeOut();  
    }
    else
    {
        $('.text').fadeIn();
    }
    pos = mywindow.scrollTop();
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily apply your image as background image and fix it.

Example CSS:

```
body {
   background-image: url('your_image.jpg');
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

It will stay fixed but the page's contents will scroll like normal *above* that background image.

Answer (score 1):

To put the logo in the top right corner and make it stay, you need to give it a `position: fixed` and the place it in the corner (with html or top/left/margins in css). You may also want to give it a higher `z-index` to ensure it stays on top. I would provide code example but I'm on my mobile right now.

Now that I'm back, here is some sample code to get you started.

```
#logo {
    position: fixed; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see @Mischback's answer for CSS background-image.

Please see the very useful fancyBox.js utility with regard to your image inquery.

The fancyBox jQuery pluggin makes image manipulation and viewing [Super Easy](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/).

I will let someone else anwer how to fix/lock a logo to the top of the screen when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mischback but I would actually put the image in its own  instead of the body.

HTML

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

CSS

```
#image {
     background-image: url('image.jpg');
     background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```